# Why is the selected icon not highlighted in BottomNavigationViewEx?

Tags: java, android

i have used BottomNavigationViewEx library in my app, however, selected icon is not being highlighted.

i wanted to turn off animations so i set labelVisibilityMode to unlabeled, animations stopped appearing but selected item is not highlighted. I have applied itemIconTint but that change the color of all icons. This is my code:

```
<com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:id="@+id/bottomnavviewbar"
           android:background="@drawable/white_grey_border_bottom"
           app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
           app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
           app:itemIconTint="#000000">
```

---

```
public class BottomNavigationViewHelper {
    private static final String TAG = "BottomNavigationViewHel";

    public static void setupBottomNavigationView(BottomNavigationViewEx bottomNavigationViewEx)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "setupBottomNavigationView: Setting up BottomNavigationView");

        bottomNavigationViewEx.enableAnimation(true);
        bottomNavigationViewEx.enableShiftingMode(true);
        bottomNavigationViewEx.setTextVisibility(false);
        bottomNavigationViewEx.enableItemShiftingMode(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using `item.setChecked(true)`; when item is selected from the `BottomNavigationView`

**snippet**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        BottomNavigationViewEx.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        item.setChecked(true);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Hope this solves your issue